# How is it that the Bene Gesserit are trusted when doctors are not?

Tags: dune

The Bene Gesserit are a secret and mysterious school of mental and physical training for women. Those who complete the training possess almost superhuman powers of psychological manipulation, as well as combat and survival skills.

Although they present themselves as a sort of religious order who exist "only to serve", the Dune universe is not one where a claim like that could be taken at face value. It seems to be common knowledge that they have an agenda of their own, and the fact that they are often called "witches" suggests that people do understand that they have unusual powers, and that there is a degree of fear and distrust as a result.

In the Dune universe, doctors require supposedly unbreakable psychological conditioning before they can be trusted not to become assassins. Wouldn't the noble houses and the emperor want a similar guarantee before allowing the Bene Gesserit to become counsellors, or intimate life partners?

Comment: The Bene Gesserit are basically the equivalent of their own noble house. They have their own planet, schools and etc. Doctors, on the other hand are just hired (albeit honoured) servants

Comment: That is similar to the way the first universities were on equal status with feudal estates in the Middle Ages. But it doesn't explain how readily the ruling classes accept them into their lives, despite clearly being potentially dangerous.

Comment: Withe the Bene Gesserit there's a strong chance of being bred.  With Doctor assassins a strong chance of being dead.  Which is better?

Comment: The BG were popularly believed to have (unspecified) powers. But the extent of what they could actually do was not known: even Thufir Hawat, spymaster and mentat, was shocked when Jessica revealed it to him.

Comment: Who said they were trusted? Dune isn't all that unlike Game of Thrones. They couldn't trust anyone in there, but would you do, become a monk to not get killed by anyone?

Comment: @Mithoron the fact that the noble houses don't appear to take any special countermeasures to control the BG seems to suggest a high level of trust, whether this is wise given that the BG appear to be a law unto themselves and regularly interfere with their dynastic succession as well as other intrigues, is another matter :-)

Comment: The Bene Gesserit were truth-speakers.  There is an old question of "would you rather be able to detect the presence of falsehood or the absence of truth" and to be a truth-speaker you must be able to do both.  Imagine a spy who had that "power".  If they were just fair, they could determine ways to get nearly anything they wanted, serve nearly any agenda.  The guild was terrified of having reverend Gaius Hellena Mohiam (sp?) in the presence of a Guild Navigator talking with Shaddam IV about their critical dependency on spice and for good reason: the guild were no fools,

Comment: The Bene Gesserit are *very* good at controlling how they are perceived by the general populace.

Answer (score 1):

Fear and distrust need not come together, in real life as well as in the *Dune* novels (at least in the FH ones): fear is triggered by memories of past, real or mythical *tragedies* and distrust, of past *betrayals*. In the Dune universe, the relevant parallel is not between MD's and Bene Gesserit: if, like me, you consider ordinary MD's are to ordinary women as the Bene Suk is to the Bene Gesserit, there is no paradox.

In this universe, the primary function of doctors is to repair the human body; the primary function of women is to produce offspring and to protect them from threats to their life. How much their respective partners trust them is essentially left to their discretion, as in real life.

The Bene Suk (resp. Bene Gesserit) came to prominence after *actual* instances of recruiting MD's (resp. sexual partners) in assassination attempts. Both provide the same kind of services as the vanilla variety, with the additional, expressed guarantee that they cannot be pressured into betrayal. They are too costly for the populace, only the political elite targeted by assassins can afford them.

Both are held in high reverence, which is a form of fear; this comes from their seemingly supernatural powers. The BS have unlimited resilience to moral torture; the BG have Trushsaying and unlimited charisma, they exact unconditional loyalty from their consorts. The BG also exert tight control over the sex of their offspring; for all we (the general public) know, the techniques for achieving this may be known to the BS and they refrain, in contrast to the BG and for reasons as shady as theirs, from thwarting the course of Nature.

These special powers and the contrasting uses they are put to, have equal potential to bring about destruction and grief, in the form of political and military crises; together with the same observed effect of protecting against betrayals. So, fear comes hand in hand with the suspicion of ulterior motives; it makes them neither a cause nor a consequence of distrust. In other words, ulterior motives are not unethical until proven otherwise. In constrast, distrust comes from a known history of breaching *explicit* guarantees. Both schools command trust to the exact extent that they maintain an impeccable record in this respect, not that they minimize the impact of man-made disasters.

Note that, contrary to what the OP implies, the trust is not absolute and BS and BG are equal in this regard: under the assumption the Atreides have left a traitor in their ranks after the normal countermeasures, both Dr Yueh and Lady Jessica are possible suspects. By Piter De Vries' reckoning, any mentat would investigate Yueh first, because it is empirically the case that the Suk conditioning can be broken; however, with the adequate framing-up, the Atreides mentat will prioritize Jessica in his stead.

Comment: The Suk doctors were trusted, not because of their impeccable track record, but because they were thought to be incapable of committing treason. In the case of the BG there was no such constraint.

Comment: I would think if you were a member of a noble house in the Dune universe, it would not be true to say "distrust comes from a known history of breaching explicit guarantees". There is always a first time! Distrust would be more a matter of "what is this person capable of doing to me". If their exact capabilities are unknown, that would increase the distrust. As mentioned, the Suk addressed this by (supposedly) putting assasination and treason outside their capabilities.

Comment: *Distrust would be more a matter of "what is this person capable of doing to me".* In real life, this is risk assessment, not distrust. Distrust is "Forget the Hippocratic oath; broke as he is, he is quite able to prescribe a dangerous dose if he knows I put him on my will"; "she promissed to warn me if we ever need condoms again; yet all I have is her word and a 2yr-old HIV test".

Comment: Without wanting to get sidetracked over precise definitions, what I was hoping to find out was why the noble houses are willing to allow the BG to get close to them. They are known to be able to exert irresistible control using their voice. Wouldn't that make them risky to have around? They don't take risks like that with their doctors.

Comment: The answer I offer is: to benefit from the services of *any* doctor or *any* geisha, you must lower your guard and risk their taking advantage of it. In both cases all you can do to mitigate the risk is to make them promise they won't. Only Suk doctors and BG geishas have a perfect record of being true to this promise.

Comment: Geisha in the general sense of: trained provider of sexual services.

Comment: The Suk doctors had their imperial conditioning, which was supposed to make it psychologically impossible for them to take advantage in that way. It was more than just a promise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152250/discussion-between-francois-jurain-and-batperson).